# Empty library in DaVinci Resolve

Tags: color-grading, davinci-resolve

I just wanted to work through the DaVinci Lite's manual. It says, the library browser should display all available volumes (Fixed, network and removable).

It displays, however, only one empty, cryptic "c:\vol0"

Any idea how I can access my footage?

Re-Installing the package didn't help.

I'm using version 11.3.0lite004 on Windows 8.1.

[image: Empty Library Browser]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just received an answer on another forum:

1. Select "DaVinci Resolve" from the main menu, select "Preferences"
2. In the media storage tab press "+" and select the desired folder / drive.
3. Press OK and restart DaVinci.

OK, this software is definitely not intuitive, and one should not read the first 100 pages of the manual too fast!

[image: Select desired folder in DaVinci]

Comment: Many thanks to Herja for the answer! https://www.gutefrage.net/frage/leerer-library-browser-in-davinci-resolve#answer-161183939